# RLE8 image support/decompression with Pillow (PIL fork)

Tags: python, bitmap, python-imaging-library, vips

I'm using Pillow (version 5.2.0) on Python3 to open both PNG and BMP images, and display them with a Tkinter GUI. The PNG images display correctly with no issues, however, I'm encountering an IOError ("Unsupported BMP compression") with some of the BMP images, when Pillow's BmpImagePlugin.py is used.

Using the bitmap plugin's [source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/2fa54408d46411be9978e3b7ec6a5c70f44e09ab/src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py) and some print statements, I found that the exception is thrown at line 193, and that the images causing the exception are compressed using RLE8 (denoted by the dictionary on line 63); all others work because they're a RAW format. 
It would seem to me that if a compression type is listed in that dictionary it should be supported, but apparently that isn't the case.

My question: is anyone aware of a workaround in Pillow or of any other python library that can open RLE8 bitmap images?
Here's an image displaying my PATH environment, as well as the command-line error described in a comment below.

[image: Edit:]

Path issues

[image: 2nd Edit]

Comment: Do you have an *"unhappy "* RLE8 image lying around that you can share for testing please?

Comment: That appears to be PNG rather than BMP.

Comment: Sorry, the hosting website converted it. This one should work http://www.filedropper.com/test_1995

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry about that Mark; the website decided to delete my images. I've created a GitHub issue that has three images in a zip file at the bottom.    https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3425

Comment: Mark, I noticed that in order to install pyvips, [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/install.html) is also needed. Are you aware of any way to install them both programmatically? By that I mean, with Pillow I was able to run 'pip install pillow' in powershell, and then simply import Pillow in my python program, and it worked. Is it possible to do that with pyvips?

Comment: Sorry, not sure, I don’t use Windows or Powershell. Maybe @user894763 would know as he developed and maintains `pyvips`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note that your first image (`test1.bmp`) appears to be corrupt and **ImageMagick** reports it has incorrect length.

Your second image does not appear to be compressed with RLE8 compression and also is a palettised image, but with alpha/transparency.

Your third image is palletised, non-alpha with RLE8 compression.

My version of PIL can read only the second file - the first and third, which are RLE encoded cannot be read.

---

You asked for a workaround - may I suggest [`pyvips`](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) which can read the files without issues:

```
import pyvips
from PIL import Image

# Load troublesome file using vips, and write to a memory buffer
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file('test1.bmp')
mem_img = image.write_to_memory()

# Read from memory buffer into Numpy array
imgnp=np.frombuffer(mem_img, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(image.height, image.width, 3)
# Convert Numpy array to PIL Image and write to disk
Image.fromarray(imgnp).save('result.png')
```

Comment: Oh no problem, just a tiny thing. Thanks for mentioning pyvips!

Comment: @jcupitt : would it be possible to install pyvips programmatically (as mentioned above in my comment on my question)?

Comment: Hi, sure, download the libvips zipfile from eg. https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download/v8.7.0/vips-dev-w64-all-8.7.0.zip then unzip, add the `vips-x.y.z/bin` dir to `%PATH%`, run `pip install pyvips` and launch Python.

Comment: I uninstalled and then reinstalled all components according to instructions you posted [here](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/44#issuecomment-390160980), and running `vips` in command line gives me the same result as [this](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/issues/44#issuecomment-394628537) individual, but then attempting to run `import pyvips` results in an error, the last line reads `cannot load library 'C:\vips-dev-8.7\vips-dev-8.7\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll': error 0xc1`, any suggestions? I tried reordering C:\vips-dev-8.7\vips-dev-8.7\bin to top of path variables, no success there.

Comment: `PATH` variable, or `PYTHONPATH` surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have to admit, I haven't heard of `PYTHONPATH` before. I moved vips to the top of my environment variables, by way of `My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables`. I lament the fact that I can't post a picture on an SO comment..

Comment: You can click `edit` under your original question and add images.

Comment: Thanks, I included one up top. @jcupitt, would it help at all to try and recompile from the source tar.gz?

Comment: You probably have a DLL conflict. I would set PATH from within Python instead. I've revised the install instructions here: https://github.com/libvips/pyvips/#install-pyvips I tested and it seems fine on my win10 PC, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I wouldn't try building libvips yourself on Windows, unless you are very skilled. It's probably a week's work for an experienced developer. There's an automated build system here: https://github.com/libvips/build-win64 it might make a useful starting point.

Comment: @jcupitt I tried the update suggestion, but got the same result, I posted an image above.

Comment: I know very little about Windows, but would point out that your Python looks 32-bit to my untrained eye and John's notes look 64-bit. I may be completely wrong, I'm just saying...

Comment: Yes, I agree with Mark, I think you have a 32-bit Python. You need 64-bit for the official libvips binary.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I changed to 64-bit; checked with `sys.version` and now the program is running with 3.7.1 64-bit, and I can import pyvips without any issues. however, when I try Mark's above workaround in my program, it's throwing the following error: `imgnp = np.frombuffer(mem_img, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(image.height, image.width, 3)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 480000 into shape (600,800,3)`

Comment: Ok, I'm now going to guess your image is greyscale and therefore only has 1 channel of grey values, rather than three channels of RGB. If so, you need `reshape(600,800)` or maybe `reshape(600,800,1)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, @MarkSetchell and jcupitt, for your patience and your help with all of this.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. Many thanks, as always to John @jcupitt

Comment: @jcupitt Sorry to bother again, just a quick question: there aren't any issues with pyvips/libvips on Windows 7, are there? Asking because I'm trying to now implement this fix on an older device, and it isn't performing as expected.

Comment: Sorry, no idea :( It used to work (I used libvips on NT back in the day), but I've only tried the current build on win10.

Comment: I'm getting this, `VipsForeignLoad: "test.bmp" is not a known file format`, although those same images displayed on W10. Would there be any **kwargs/load option I could try for `new_from_file()` that could fix this error, or does the W7 OS simply not support some features of libvips? I wasn't able to find a 'vips jpegload' for bitmaps.